# Resume app when tapping a received toast notification

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to open my app when a user taps the received toast notification. I have setup the server to post this message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
  <wp:Toast>
    <wp:Text1>Message</wp:Text1>
    <wp:Text2>Resume application</wp:Text2>
  </wp:Toast>
</wp:Notification>
```

When my app is in the background (or fully closed) I'm getting a notification as expected but when I tap the notification it will just open the app and run my main page.

Instead, I would like it to:

- if app closed => open main page (as it does now)
- **if app in background => resume app**

I have tried with the "wp:Param" argument as well with both a absolute url to a page (which is not what I want) and by starting with "?" (to indicate it should transfer that parameter to the main page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the internal mechanism works, the application will always launch in a new instance when called from a toast.

Comment: I don't question your answer but do you have a link in the official documentation where I'm able to read more about this?